# Fill dataframe with duplicate data until a certain conditin is met

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a data frame df like,

```
id name age duration
1  ABC  20   12
2  sd   50   150
3  df   54   40
```

i want to duplicate this data in same df until the duration sum is more than or equal to 300,

so the df can be like..

```
id name age duration
1  ABC  20   12
2  sd   50   150
3  df   54   40
2  sd   50   150
```

**so far i have tried the below code, but this is running in infinite loop sometimes :/ .
please help.**

```
def fillPlaylist(df,duration):
    print("inside fill playlist fn.")
    if(len(df)==0):
        print("df len is 0, cannot fill.")
        return df;

    receivedDf= df
    print("receivedDf",receivedDf,flush=True)
    print("Received df len = ",len(receivedDf),flush=True)
    print("duration to fill ",duration,flush=True)
    while df['duration'].sum() < duration:
        # random 5% sample of data.
        print("filling")
        ramdomSampleDuplicates = receivedDf.sample(frac=0.05).reset_index(drop=True)
        df = pd.concat([ramdomSampleDuplicates,df])
        print("df['duration'].sum() ",df['duration'].sum())
    print("after filling df len = ",len(df))
    return df;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `n` instead of `frac`.

`n` randomly sample n rows from your dataframe.

```
sample_df = df.sample(n=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

To use `frac` you can rewrite your code in this way.

```
def fillPlaylist(df,duration):
    while df.duration.sum() < duration:
        sample_df = df.sample(frac=0.5).reset_index(drop=True)
        df = pd.concat([df,sample_df])
    return df
```

Comment: thanks can you please explain how does this works and  by using frac it was not working?

Comment: @R.singh your methods should work too. `frac` sample a fraction of rows in dataframe and `n` randonly sample n rows from your dataframe.

However, replace `receivedDf= df `, `receivedDf= df.copy()`.

Comment: @R.singh i have rewrite the code using `frac` for your use case. Do approve the solution if it helps :)